# Android Studio - HAX kernel Module not installed

Tags: java, android, kernel, development-environment, virtualization

i installed Android Studio for Windows.

I got an AMD 7850K processor and an A78M-E35 Mainboard.

I cant run the emulator because the Installer for the HAX Module is only for Intel.

What alternatives do i have for running the emulator with an AMD?

Greets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many posts on this forum suggest Genymotion.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answer.

With that i found an appropriate answer for myself:

It's possible to change the image for the emulator - so it would be possible to use genymotion. But a much easier for me is to change the image to arm instead of x86.

Now it works without problems.

Tank you!

Greets.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to run the emulator and i got the error message about hardware acceleration and the Hax kernel module error. This fixed my error:

1) try enabling your virtualization technology by entering BIOS at startup.

2) follow this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z7xoPCv3sYs

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include a summary of the video.